# How to extend line until end of image

Tags: matlab

Lets say, i have a line and i want to extend the line until the end of the image.
 The line is displayed in the first photo with the green is my basic line, i want to extend it like the second image, until the end of the image.
 I want to do this for all the lines that i have detected.
 Does anyone knows how to do this?

[image: original line]

[image: extended line]

Comment: I think i found it

Answer (score 1):

i think i found it

```
X= [x1, x2]
Y=[y1, y2]

c = [[1; 1]  X(:)]\Y(:);    
slope_m = c(2)
intercept_b = c(1)

aLine = [slope_m,-1,intercept_b];
points = lineToBorderPoints(aLine,size(negfillHoles))
line(points([1 ,3]),points([2 ,4]),'LineWidth',1.5,'Color','r');
 plot(x1,y1,'*','LineWidth',2,'Color','g');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this approach:

- convert RGB image to HSV (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html)
- in the H plane select only the green pixels
- apply the Hough transform (https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/hough.html)
- draw the complete line